# How to catch a constructor exception?

Tags: c++, constructor, exception

I have a C++ class which throws an exception from the constructor on failure. How can I allocate a local instance of this class (without using `new`) and handle any possible exceptions, while keeping the `try` block scope as small as possible?

Essentially, I am looking for the C++ equivalent of the following Java idiom:

```
boolean foo() {
    Bar x;
    try {
        x = new Bar();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
    x.doSomething();
    return true;
}
```

I do not want to catch exceptions from `x.doSomething()`, **only the constructor**.

I suppose what I'm looking for is a way to separate the declaration and the initialization of `x`.

Is it possible to accomplish this without using heap allocations and pointers?

Comment: Yes. Put everything on the successful path inside the try block. You'll stay in function scope.

Comment: @StoryTeller what if I don't want to catch exceptions from e.g. `x.doSomething()`, only exceptions from the constructor?

Comment: @AndrewSun Use different exceptions, or put `x.doSomething()` in an inner exception block.

Comment: C++ exceptions are pretty expensive (for c++ speed junkies). You shouldn't throw them willy-nilly to begin with, unlike in Java. If you already do, than redesign your exception hierarchy and re-throw stuff from `x.doSomething();`

Comment: Do you know **what exception** you want to catch? Memory allocation can fail *and* the constructor code can fail...

Comment: Ahh, this is about scope. If `Bar x;` is put in the `try` block, the scope of `x` will be limited to the `try` block. Hence `x` will be out of scope for `x.doSometing()`, unless it it also moved into the `try` block. But moving it would change the exception handling behaviour to also catch exceptions from `x.doSomething()`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [std::optional](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) from C++17:

```
bool foo() {
    std::optional<Bar> x; // x contains nothing; no Bar constructed
    try {
        x.emplace();      // construct Bar (via default constructor)
    } catch (const Exception& e) {
        return false;
    }
    x->doSomething();     // call Bar::doSomething() via x (also (*x).doSomething() )
    return true;
}
```

Comment: @Jarod42 I hesitated for how to write it for defualt ctor of `Bar`. `x.emplace()`? `x.emplace({})`?

Comment: It is `x.emplace()` for default constructor. The later won't compile.

Comment: good answer, Though I though returning from a catch block was not a good idea. You could instead make the catch just suppress the exception, and the test `x` to decide when to return. (i.e. `if (!x) return false;`)

Comment: @nate: C++ is a multiple-exit language. All code needs to be designed to deal with multiple exits. There's nothing wrong with returning from the `catch` block. On the contrary, not doing it would be a needless complication.

Answer (score 6):

This Java idiom doesn't translate well to C++ since `Bar x;` will require  *default constructor* even if your real constructor requires arguments to be passed.

I'd advise fighting the language to this degree - widening the `try` block is sufficient - but if you *really* want to narrow then you *could* use a function and rely on *return value optimisation* to obviate a value copy:

```
Bar foobar()
{
    try {
        return Bar();
    } catch (Exception& e){
        /* Do something here like throwing a specific construction exception
           which you intercept at the call site.*/
    }
}
```

But really, you could throw a specific exception on construction, so obviating this function approach entirely.

Comment: RVO & move semantics make this the best solution in my opinion.

Comment: Prior to c++17, OP has so to handle as well copy/move constructor exception.

Comment: @Jarod42, what did c++17 change? (Just asking for the sake of my own curiosity).

Comment: @StoryTeller: prior to c++17, (N)RVO was allowed. In C++17, it is required (in some cases).

Comment: "Do something here like throwing a specific construction exception" — the coonstructor is already doung this, no need to wrap it in a funtion. If you do think this is beneficial, please show how to handle exceptions thrown by your function.

Comment: Absolutely, hence my final sentence. The real moral of the story is to not fight the language.

Answer (score 5):

Yes it's possible, if you put all the code in the `try` clause, for example by using a [function try block](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function-try-block) (to avoid unnecessary nesting and scoping):

```
bool foo() try
{
    Bar x;
    x.doSomething();
    return true;
}
catch (std::exception const& e)
{
    return false;
}
```

Or in the `try` clause call another function which does the real work:

```
void real_foo()
{
    Bar x;
    x.doSomething();
}

bool foo() try
{
    real_foo();
    return true;
}
catch (std::exception const& e)
{
    return false;
}
```

Note that it's often not a good idea to throw exceptions in a constructor, as that will halt the construction of the object, and its destructor will not be called.

---

As noted by Holt, this will also catch exceptions from the `doSomething` call. There are two ways of solving that:

1. The simple and standard way: *Use pointers*.
2. Use two-stage construction: Have a default constructor which can't throw exceptions, then call a special "construct" function that can throw exceptions.

The second way was common before C++ was standardized, and used extensively in code for the [Symbian system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbian). It is not common any more since using pointers for this is much more easy and simpler, especially today with good smart pointers available. I really don't recommend the second way in modern C++.

The easiest way is of course to make sure that the constructor can't throw exceptions at all, or if any is thrown then they are of the nature that the program can't continue anyway and have the program be terminated. As noted in the comments to your question, exceptions in C++ are expensive, and then we also have the abandoned construction issue, and in all using exceptions in C++ should only be done in exceptional cases. C++ is not Java, you should not treat it as such even if there are similar constructs in both languages.

If you still want to throw exceptions from the constructor there is actually a third way to catch only those: Use one of the code-example up top, and throw only specific exceptions that `doSomething` can never throw and then catch these specific constructors only.

Comment: function try block is not needed. Regular `try catch` is enough.

Comment: @Jarod42, then `Bar` must be in another block, not at function level block.

Comment: This will not mimic the behavior of the given java code since you will catch exceptions from `x.doSomething()`.

Comment: @Holt "will not mimic the behavior of the given java code" when writing in C++ one normally wants to write in idiomatic C++ rather than mimic some other language.

Comment: @n.m. Writing in idiomatic C++ should not prevent you from maintaining the *observable* behavior of the program (I think there are c++ ways to obtain the same behavior without having to rely on java-like code).

Comment: **−1** "There are two ways of solving that:", that is incorrect and very very bad advice. There is no need to incur the overhead of dynamic allocation. There is no need to incur the plain Evil™ of two stage construction.

Comment: "make sure that the constructor can't throw exceptions at all". Totally wrong and interferes with RAII. Don't do that.

Answer (score 2):

You have to choose between variant of

```
bool foo() {
    std::unique_ptr<Bar> x;
    try {
        x = std::make_unique<Bar>();
    } catch (const BarConstructorException& e) {
        return false;
    }
    x->doSomething();
    return true;
}
```

or

```
bool foo() {
    try {
        Bar x;
        x.doSomething();
    } catch (const BarConstructorException& e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Normally if you want to avoid heap allocations, you can't separate the declaration of a local variable from its definition. So if you were to combine everything in a single function, you would have to do surround the entire scope of `x` with `try/catch` block:

```
boolean foo() {
    try {
        Bar x;
        x.doSomething();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No. From your java example, you will have to choose between these 2 possibilities:

Without pointers:

```
bool foo() {
    try {
        Bar x;
        x.doSomething();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

With pointers:

```
bool foo() {
    Bar* x = nullptr;
    try {
        x = new Bar();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
    x->doSomething();

    delete x; // don't forget to free memory

    return true;
}
```

Or using managed pointers:

```
#include <memory>

bool foo() {
    std::unique_ptr<Bar> x;
    try {
        x = new Bar();               // until C++14
        x = std::make_unique<Bar>(); // since C++14
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
    x->doSomething();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You might want to add a `delete x` somewhere ;)

Comment: Yep. The downside of the second example as you have it now is, you really want to catch any exceptions in `x->doSomething` to make sure the `delete` gets executed, but then you need a separate try-catch block with a rethrow -- potential headaches that the `unique_ptr` solves nicely. Good that you added it.

Answer (score 1):

In the revised question the OP adds the requirement that

> **”**  I do not want to catch exceptions from `x.doSomething()`, only the constructor [of the local variable].

A simple way to translate the Java code

```
boolean foo() {
    Bar x;
    try {
        x = new Bar();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
    x.doSomething();
    return true;
}
```

… to C++, is then to use an `Optional_` class (like Barton-Nackmann `Fallible`, `boost::optional` or C++17 `std::optional`)

```
auto foo()
    -> bool
{
    Optional_<Bar> xo;
    try
    {
        xo.emplace();
    }
    catch( ... )
    {
        return false;
    }

    Bar& x = *xo;
    // Possibly other code here, then:
    x.doSomething();
    return true;
}
```

A nice alternative is to refactor that code, like this:

```
struct Something_failure {};

void do_something( Bar& o )
{
    // Possibly other code here, then:
    o.doSomething();
}

auto foo()
    -> bool
{
    try
    {
        Bar x;

        do_something( x );
        return true;
    }
    catch( Something_failure const& )
    {
        throw;
    }
    catch( ... )
    {}
    return false;
}
```

If you do not like the above approaches then you can always go for a dynamically allocated `Bar` instance, e.g. using a `std::unique_ptr` for guaranteed cleanup, which however has the general overhead of a dynamic allocation. In Java most every object is dynamically allocated so that might not seem to be a serious disadvantage. But in C++ most objects are superfast stack-allocated so that a dynamic allocation is a *very* slow operation compared to ordinary operations, so the possible conceptual simplicity of dynamic allocation must be weighted against that.